# I would like to add multiple Strings to my android Button programmatically (not through XML)

Tags: java, android, xml, button

I'm trying to format the three Strings into an android button. The first string should be about 30% of the button, second should be about 50%, and the rest to the third button. Each text should be contrained within a certain length. How can I do this?

After searching through many possible solutions, what I came up with was to create 3 different buttons and put them together. This wouldn't be ideal but it's a start. Are there better ways to do this?

This is what I have tried so far:

The Java:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout_buttons);
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Button addButton = new Button(this);
Button numPlayerButton = new Button(this);
Button lobbyButton = new Button(this);
Button locationButton = new Button(this);

ll.addView(addButton, lp);
ll.addView(numPlayerButton, lp);
ll.addView(lobbyButton, lp);
ll.addView(locationButton, lp);
```

XML:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout_buttonlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout_buttons"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <!-- THIS IS WHERE THE BUTTONS GO!!!!!! -->
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

My goal with this code was to have the buttons created horizontally with the inner linear layout, and I thought the outer linear layout will create the next iteration of buttons on the next line (vertically). I have the buttons created programmatically through a loop.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can I suggest you post a minimal sample showing the approach you're using now, so that other users can see if there's a better way for you?

Comment: my current way is just a simple button, I have not implemented anything yet to do this because im not sure how to approach it.

Comment: ans of Daniel Mi is perfect.. go with that..
if you not using fragment than just remove the "view" in the first line only, that would work for you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to click a widget then do something(as a button does), you can use a Layout and add a onClickListener to it. In this Layout, you can add strings as you want.

Simply do it like that:

1. Write a RelativeLayout in your XML and give it a id.
2. Add three textViews in RelativeLayout and place them as you want.
3. Register this RelativeLayout in Java and add a onClickListener to it.

For Java part:

```
RelativeLayout ThreeStringLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.three_string_layout);
            ThreeStringLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view1) {
                    //do things here
                }
            });
```

I implemented it in a Fragment, you need to modify it if you use it in Activity.
Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be achieved using a standard Android Button (that I know of). You will have to use a linear layout with textviews. I can explain how that would work if need help

Comment: Yes please I would like an explanation, that would help!